# Dynamic Array of Structures within a Structure Declaration

Tags: c, struct, arduino, malloc

I am implementing the following:

```
struct f
{
//some simple variables here
};

struct p
{
//more simple variables here
struct f fbs[X]; //where x can be between 1-4 and is determined from a variable ran after the code 
                //begins to run
};

struct t
{
struct p pts[4]; //will always contain 4 elements/objects
//finally some more simple variables
};
```

I am wondering how I can create this array `fbs` to be dynamic as the value of `x` can vary between 1-4. I was going to use pre-processor directives with `#if` statements etc but that would not allow the variable to be changed during runtime.

From what I could find some use of `malloc` is required, but I haven't found any solutions so far.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless `struct f` is HUGE, just declare `fbs[4]` and keep count of how many are filled.

Comment: there will be approximately 96-288 of these structures.

What will happen is that these will be populated by a database. The problem being that the size of these structures will also be used for graphical purposes (e.g if there is fbs[4] when only 2 are filled, surely this will cause larger issues down the line

Comment: No, regardless of whether you allocate or whether you use a fixed size array, how you use the storage is the same. You either keep a counter of the number of elements filled, or you use a sentinel-element (such as `NULL` or all members zero, etc.., similar to the way a C-string uses `'\0'`) as the next element after the last valid element in your array. Those are the only two methods that allow you to iterate over the elements in your array or know how-many. A counter is preferred as you don't have to iterate each time you want to know how-many, but either way will work.

Comment: Still confused, as the constructor for this structure will be creating 3 structures at once - with the final element in the final struct being this fbs[] array. As far as I am aware within structs I cannot use statements like if etc. so how would I then skip over an element in fbs[] such that it is not filled with incorrect data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by `"skip over an element in fbs[] such that it is not filled"` in the last comment, but I think you can approach constructing `struct p` by keeping a member count of the number of elements desired (say `int n;`) providing the number of array elements to fill within `fbs[4]`. That way both `pts[4]` and `fbs[4]` are fixed size, but you only utilize `n` elements in `fbs[]`

A short example will explain. Begin with your `struct f` with `"some simple variables"` like `int a, b, c;`, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

#define NFBS 4

struct f
{
    int a, b, c;    /* some simple variables */
    
    /* construct f */
    f (int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0) : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
    
    /* overload of << to output variables */
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const f& fs) {
        std::cout << "  " << fs.a << "  " << fs.b << "  " << fs.c << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};
```

Above is just a straight-forward initialization of `a`, `b`, and `c`, the overload of `<<` in each struct just provides a simple way to output and illustrate usage.

Now for `struct p`, keep the declaration of `fbs` a fixed size `fbs[NFBS]`, but add a member variable `int n;` that holds the number of elements in `fbs` that are actually in use, e.g.

```
struct p
{
    int n;                      /* no. of elements (0 <= n < NFBS) */
    struct f fbs[NFBS];         /* array of struct f */
    
    p (int i = 0) : n(i)        /* construct n struct f in fbs array */
    { 
        if (n > NFBS) {         /* validate n */
            std::cerr << "error: struct p initial value out-of-range.\n";
            /* handle error */
        }
        else {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                fbs[k] = f(k+1, k+2, k+3);  /* handle as desired */
        }
    }
    
    /* overload of << to output variables */
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const p& ps) {
        std::cout << "have fbs[" << ps.n << "]\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < ps.n; i++)
            std::cout <<  "  fbs[" << i << "]: " << ps.fbs[i];
        return os;
    }
};
```

Above, the constructor initializes `n` elements of `fbs`. (dummy values used for example). The number of elements requested is validated against the max of `NFBS` -- you will need to handle the error if it is out-of-range however you like.

Finally for `struct t`, you add the same counter member `int n` to construct `p(n)` and initialize each element of `pts`, e.g.

```
struct t
{
    int n;                      /* no. of elements for struct p fbs[n] */
    struct p pts[NFBS];         /* array of struct p */
    
    t (int i = 0) : n(i)        /* constuct NFBS struct p, each initialized p(n) */
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < NFBS; k++)
            pts[k] = p(n);      /* handle as desired */
    }
    
    /* overload of << to output variables */
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const t& ts) {
        std::cout << "\nhave pts[" << NFBS << "]\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < NFBS; i++)
            std::cout <<  "\npts[" << i << "]: " << ts.pts[i];
        return os;
    }
};
```

So `t` always has `pts[4]` each initialized to a `struct p` having `fbs` with between `0-4` elements each. A short `main()` implementing the above for cases where `struct p` has `2` and then `4` elements in `fbs` used would be:

```
int main () {
    
    t foo{2}, bar{4};
    
    std::cout << foo << bar;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/multi_struct_arr

have pts[4]

pts[0]: have fbs[2]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4

pts[1]: have fbs[2]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4

pts[2]: have fbs[2]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4

pts[3]: have fbs[2]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4

have pts[4]

pts[0]: have fbs[4]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4
  fbs[2]:   3  4  5
  fbs[3]:   4  5  6

pts[1]: have fbs[4]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4
  fbs[2]:   3  4  5
  fbs[3]:   4  5  6

pts[2]: have fbs[4]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4
  fbs[2]:   3  4  5
  fbs[3]:   4  5  6

pts[3]: have fbs[4]
  fbs[0]:   1  2  3
  fbs[1]:   2  3  4
  fbs[2]:   3  4  5
  fbs[3]:   4  5  6
```

Not knowing more on how you intend to implement this nested set of structs, it is hard to be more precise, but this was my initial thought on how you can handle the differing number of elements wanted in `fbs` in different instances of `struct p`.